# How can we convert sql 5.6 query to 5.7

Tags: sql, mysql-5.7, mysql-5.6

I m facing an issues in sql query
It worked with previous version - 5.6

But now its not working with version 5.7
So anyone can help me to convert this query to sql 5.7

```
SELECT to_startdate, to_enddate  
FROM tour 
WHERE  to_name !='' 
   AND to_startdate !='0000-00-00' 
   AND to_deactivated !=1 
GROUP BY MONTH(to_startdate), YEAR(to_startdate) 
ORDER BY to_startdate
```

Comment: Share the error log, if any.

Comment: 5.6 and 5.7, what is that? MySQL versions?

Comment: Why GROUP BY when no aggregate functions are involved?

Comment: @jarlh yes im checking this by "select @@version"

Comment: @jarlh i need to show these values my month and year

Comment: sample data and output is helpful

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin ?????

Comment: Please post the error message you are getting so that we don't have to guess what the problem is.

Comment: My guess is that the  `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY ` setting has been changed by the upgrade but who really knows as long as OP refuses to post the error message or further explain why the query doesn't work..

Comment: @Nick 

MySQL said: Documentation

#1055 - Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'jungle_search.tour.to_startdate' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by


this is the error im getting when I run query

Comment: @Mandeep this will probably help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115174/error-related-to-only-full-group-by-when-executing-a-query-in-mysql

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want the code to do.

Comment: @GordonLinoff
expected result :- https://websearchsolutions.in/url/junglelore/tripcalendar.php

Result which I'm Getting :- http://junglelore.net/tripcalendar.php

Same query is used on both :- "SELECT to_startdate,to_enddate FROM tour WHERE  to_name !='' AND to_startdate !='0000-00-00' AND to_deactivated !=1 GROUP BY MONTH(to_startdate),YEAR(to_startdate) ORDER BY to_startdate"

Answer (score 0):

Your query doesn't make sense in general -- the `select` references columns and these are not aggregated.  You can use aggregation functions.  I don't know what values you want, but something like this:

```
SELECT MIN(to_startdate), MIN(to_enddate)  
FROM tour 
WHERE to_name <> ''  AND
      to_startdate <> '0000-00-00' AND
      to_deactivated <> 1 
GROUP BY MONTH(to_startdate), YEAR(to_startdate) 
ORDER BY MIN(to_startdate)
```

Comment: `SELECT MIN(to_startdate), MIN(to_enddate)  
FROM tour 
WHERE to_name !='' AND
      to_startdate !='0000-00-00' AND
      to_deactivated !=1 
GROUP BY MONTH(to_startdate), YEAR(to_startdate) 
ORDER BY to_startdate`




result 
#1055 - Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'jungle_search.tour.to_startdate' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: @Mandeep . . . I fixed the `ORDER BY`.